# Fréchet–Kolmogorov improved version (without boundedness)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness

I learned that if $B$ is a bounded subset of $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then $B$ is relatively compact if

1. $\lim_{h\to0}||\tau_hf-f||_p$=0 uniformly on B
2. $\lim_{r\to\infty}\int_{|x|>r}|f|^p=0$ uniformly on B

In the Wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_theorem) it says that (1)+(2) imply that $B$ is a bounded subset. Is there a (simple) way to see this?